# 2012 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

The 2012 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://photo.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: Are we holding an election to *replace* or *supplement* the current mods (or some combination thereof)?  I think moderation of this site has been excellent, and I can see how that would be time-consuming, too, so my question isn't at all critical of the process: I only wonder about the immediate purpose of the election.

Comment: This is to supplement the existing moderators.